# Prohibit starting a form in third-part dll plugin (c# service)

Tags: c#, plugins, service

I have the a service, that loads some dlls and starts a function in each dll. Each dll contains some rules, that can be also developed by our clients (something like plugin system). The problem is, that clients can theoretically add forms to be called inside dlls. So the goal is to disallow that, or, at least block such dlls.

The only method I can imagine now is call each dll in a separate thread and kill it after some timeout.

But I think it is not so nice.
Please advice me a better method. Thankx.

Comment: If you don't trust their code, don't execute it.

Comment: I cannot do this. This is a large system with customization on a client side. And they pay for that possibility. But I cannot control each client, of course. This is a box-like product, not a product for one customer.

Comment: Then you're implicitly trusting customer code.  Why aren't you trusting them to not show UI too?

Comment: Well... actually I am not trusting them anymore... :). Probably it is a good idea to make something that disallow any kind of suspicious code (like infinite loops for example)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deal with plug-ins is to "sandbox" each one of them in an individual app domain. This way you can safely react to their execution errors, unload them if you need to, and manage them in whatever ways you like. But most importantly for this question, you can monitor their loading of assemblies using [this event hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx). If you see them loading a DLL that you do not want to allow, you can simply throw an exception. Your code would catch the exception, clean up the app domain, and optionally send the clients a warning for trying to do something that is not allowed.

The only downside to this approach is that it is rather non-trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0):

It is VERY hard problem to protect server from third party code that you need to execute.
I would recommend reading on SharePoint sandbox approach (i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx) which tries to solve this and related issues.

As SLaks said - you implicitly trust code by simply executing it. Unless you expect code to be outright evil you may be better of by simply logging how long calls take (and maybe time out if possible) and provide your client with this information. Since it seems like client creates the code for themselves it is unlikely that code will be explicitly made non-functional.

Other interesting issues outside showing a Form:

- stack overflow exception (easy to create, hard  to handle)
- `while(true);` code that never returns control
- access to native code if full trust enabled.

Comment: Well... I never asks about easy problems :). Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use reflection to inspect their code and ensure that certain namespaces and classes (e.g. System.Windows.Forms.*) are not referenced or used.

SQLCLR restricts what is allowed to be used/referenced in assemblies installed as SQLCLR extensions, and that appears to be done that way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403273.aspx